# Query prolog with PHP

Tags: php, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to make a sudoku game with PHP and prolog, the idea is to use prolog program to solve the sudoku then get the results via PHP, I have write this code down but I'm getting a empty output
I have even try to use `var_dump` to test and i'm getting `string '' (length=0)` 
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Soduku</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<?php

$output=exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\" -g \"test,halt\" -t \"halt(1)\" test.pl ");
var_dump($output);
echo $output;
echo"<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo"</pre>";

?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my code after edition

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Soduku</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<?php

exec('"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\swipl\\bin\\swipl-win.exe" -g "st,halt" -t "halt(1)"  -s test.pl',$output,$return_var);
var_dump($output);
echo $return_var;


?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

it display this result

```
array (size=0)
  empty
0
```

Comment: If I were you, first, I would open and close the `<pre>` tag outside the PHP code. Then: really, use the last argument to `exec()` too, and check if it is 0 (success) or 1. If it is really 0, then you should figure out if you are printing in the correct way. `var_dump()` is _definitely_ not going to print the contents of the array to lines.... I am afraid you really need to do some reading on your own.

Comment: when i execute the command line `"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\swipl\\bin\\swipl-win.exe" -g "st,halt" -t "halt(1)"  test.pl` in the cmd it works perfectly, but when i try to use it in the `exec()` it returns an empty output, im not really sure where is the problem, i tried to read many time that document and i can't really find where im doing it wrong, thats why im asking for help here

Comment: also `$return_var` returns 0 which mean success

Answer (score 1):

i have finnaly find out how to do it and it was too simple, i just had to excute swipl.exe instead swipl-win.exe, the right syntax is

```
$cmd='"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl.exe" -g solve_problems,halt -t halt(1) sud.pl' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) says that `exec` returns the last line and you probably have an empty line as a last line. To get the full output, use the second parameter like this:

```
exec("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe\" -g \"test,halt\" -t \"halt(1)\" test.pl ", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: i tired that also and i get this error `( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\Sudoku\index.php on line 15 ` and `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: @MessiAdrinho can you paste line 15 here?

Comment: i have change my code `exec('"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\swipl\\bin\\swipl-win.exe" -g "st,halt" -t "halt(1)"  test.pl',$output,$return_var);
var_dump($output);
echo $return_var;` i dont get that error anymore but i still have an empty output and return_var returns 0 which mean that the command line was excuted succefuly, i really can't figure out where is the problem

Comment: Messi if you run the given program from command line with the same parameters, what is the output you get? Also, do not associate the return value to $output, as $output = ... because $output is passed by reference and will get the value while the function is running. If you assign the value to $output, then you override the value with the last line, which was empty line, as described in the question.

Comment: its a simple prolog program that return "hello" and it works fine in command line, the problem is that i dont get anything when i run it via php `exec()`, output is empty and im not assigning anything to $output

Comment: @MessiAdrinho can you edit your question and paste the code you have currently?

Comment: @MessiAdrinho can you write a simple batch file which writes "Hello" and call that without any parameters? This test could help us to localize your problem.

Comment: yeh that test.pl batch is saying hello only

Comment: @MessiAdrinho can you test this without prolog files, having a simple batch without parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131451/discussion-between-messi-adrinho-and-lajos-arpad).